# how to click AlertDialog NegativeButton in python Appium api?

Tags: android, appium

I am a fresh in Appium. I use this code to show permission alert and I want to test it.

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setTitle("ALERT")
            .setMessage(reason)
            .setNegativeButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{permissionType},requestCode);
                        }
                    }).create().show();
```

I use appium desktop and python appium-client ,how to wait until this alert dialog show and then catch this NegativeButton and click it?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.switch_to_alert().accept()` can work.
it is Deprecated use driver.switch_to.alert.
`driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` can work.